# PowerMock mockStatic not mocking the class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

I have the following class(and method in it)

class Fetcher{

```
 public void fetch(String key){
      File file = File.createTempFile(key,"*.txt");
      ..... 
      ....
 }
```

}

I want to unit test this method and want to mock the createTempFile method
For this i have written the unit test as follows

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

@PrepareForTest({File.class})

public class FetcherTest {

    public void test() {
        String key = "key";
        File file = new File("Hello");
        PowerMock.mockStatic(File.class);
        EasyMock.expect(File.createTempFile(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class),EasyMock.anyObject(String.class))).andReturn(file).once();
        PowerMock.replay(File.class);
        Fetcher fetcher = new Fetcher();
        fetcher.fetch("key");
        PowerMock.verify(File.class);
    }
}
```

Executing the unit test provides the following error:

> Expectation failure on verify:    File.createTempFile(,):
>   expected: 1,actual: 0

I have looked through a lot of articles but am not able to figure out what's missing here and why File is not getting mocked. Please help with any suggestions

Comment: Is there a "PowerMock.expect()" method?  If so, you should be using that instead.

Comment: There is no expect on PowerMock but from what i have seen we use EasyMock.expect

Comment: Interesting.  I only use PowerMockito, so I'm not familiar with that variation.  I know we have to use "PowerMock.when()" to mock static method behavior.

Comment: I am wondering if this can be due to any conflicts in versions of junit and PowerMockEasyMock

Comment: where is `Easymock.replayAll();`

Answer (score 0):

When you mock Java System classes (and the `File` is a Java System Class) you have to add a [ClassThatCallsTheSystemClass](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockSystem) to `@PrepareForTest`.

So you need to add `class Fetcher` to `@PrepareForTest`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Fetcher.class})
```